# Python Anaconda Jupyter notebook doesn't launch

Tags: python, anaconda

I just downloaded and installed anaconda, and I opened the jupyther notebook from the "start" menu, it prompts a black window that looks like a command line window, but instead of opening my browser on the notebook "tree" page, it just closes the black command line window and nothing happens.

I formatted my computer and downloaded the anaconda, before it was fine and now it doesn't launch.

tried to unistall and install again but nothing...

and ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and solved it using various answers from various places. Here is what I did:

Open a terminal, then copy paste:

> conda update nb_conda nb_conda_kernels nb_anacondacloud

For me it answered that nb_conda wasn't installed, so I added:

> conda install nb_conda

From there, jupyter notebook launched properly but it ended up in no folder and stated a "servor error". I solved the problem by running it stating the folder where I wanted it to start:

> jupyter notebook C:\Users\YOURNAME\Documents\Python

It is then possible to update directly your shortcut by changing the "target" and "opens in":

> Target : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter.exe notebook
>
> Opens in : C:\Users\YOURNAME\Documents\Python

I hope that it will work all right for you, let me know if you found a better solution...